# Automatically insert a \newpage after chapter headings

Tags: memoir, chapters

I'm writing a book using `memoir`, and I'd like each chapter's text to begin on a new page after the chapter headings (so each chapter heading stands on a page by itself).

Is there a way to make this automatic, so I don't have to add the `\newpage` command after each instance of `\chapter{}`?

I tried `\renewcommand{\chapter{}}{\chapter{} \newpage}`, but it doesn't seem to work...

Here is my MWE as it stands with my current chapter header customizations:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

% Chapter headers customize
\setsecnumdepth{none}
\setlength\beforechapskip{6\baselineskip}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\sffamily \HUGE \bfseries}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
My text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: A work around would be to define `\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{\chapter{#1} \newpage}`.

Comment: @LudovicC. Thanks, that works great! So there's no way to alter (or "renew") the original `\chapter{}` command?

Comment: this is really a hack, but i've seen it used many times in error.  use a "driver file".  put the `\chapter{xxx}` command in the driver file, and immediately follow it with `\include{file-containing-the-text-of-the-chapter}`.  that'll put you right onto a new page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may redefine `\afterchaptertitle`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

% Chapter headers customize
\setsecnumdepth{none}
\setlength\beforechapskip{6\baselineskip}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\sffamily \HUGE \bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}%
    {\newpage}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
 My text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\afterchaptertitle` should be used only when defining chapter styles.

Comment: @egreg Oh? Reference please, I have redefined \afterchaptertitle for years. On page 84 in the manual it is written: ‘The macro \afterchaptertitle is called just after printing a chapter title. By default it inserts \afterchapskip space (default 40pt).’ But I admit your solution is better, but mine avoids \makeatletter and friends.

Answer (score 10):

The solution is already on page 83 of the manual:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\memendofchapterhook{%
  \clearpage\m@mindentafterchapter\@afterheading}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Sorry for commenting on 3 years old answer, but where is this `manual`?

Comment: @Zvika `texdoc memoir` on your system or http://texdoc.net (type `memoir` in the box).

Answer (score 2):

A quick work around without modifying the `\chapter` command would be:

```
\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{\chapter{#1} \newpage}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to keep the feature of the optional argument of the `\chapter` command (the short version used in the ToC and headers), you can have the following definition instead:

```
\newcommand{\mychapter}[2][]{\chapter[#1]{#2} \newpage}
```

Comment: With both approaches you lose the possibility of using the optional arguments to `\chapter`.

Comment: I guess it is possible to add an optional argument to the newcommand to add this feature, no?

Comment: @egreg Would something like this work `\newcommand{\mychapter}[2][]{\chapter[#2]{#1} \newpage}`?

Comment: `\chapter` has *two* optional arguments in `memoir`. Moreover `\chapter{Title}` would define an empty entry for the TOC.